# How to generate very Large random number in c++

Tags: c++

I want to generate very large random number in range of 0 - 2^64 using c++. I have used the rand() function but it is not generating very large number. Can any one help?

Comment: Do you want that number to be a number itself? Or just a string like Hash? Or do you prefer to have a very long number as a string?

Comment: You might want to refer to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120062/generate-random-64-bit-integer

Comment: "Very large"? A simple `std::uint64_t` can hold all those values.

Comment: @KerrekSB It is fairly large compared to what the common `rand()` can handle.

Comment: Is it really best duplicate target? Answers are awful, all of them are using `rand()` which should not be used in C++.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Sure, but shifting and oring is sufficient.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Wut? The most upvoted answer there (yes, mine) does not even mention `rand`. Besides, even if all answers in the the dupe target are bad, just add a better one there.

Comment: _@Nabeel_Afzal_ Please show how you were using `rand()` actually. Create a [MCVE], that everyone can reproduce your results.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sure, which is what the accepted answer in the dupe does. I don't get why this was reopened, who did that and why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209690/c-random-number-from-1-to-a-very-large-number-e-g-25-million/34209811#34209811

Comment: @BaummitAugen I reopened. The number to generate isn't _very large_, as Kerrek already mentioned.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why? How is that not a dupe? Did you find a better dupe? The number OP asks about is not smaller than the one over there.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: On the other hand, it's not all that large compared to what `std::uniform_int_distribution<std::uint64_t>` can handle :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB Of course, which is what I used in my answer in the first dupe. I am kind of confused by this debate tbh. 0.o

Comment: Btw, if the range is actually `[0,2^64)`, you can skip the distribution step and use the values returned by `std::mt19937_64` directly.

Comment: The duplicate doesn't address generating integers over 2^32, as the limit referred to in the question is 25 million.

Comment: I reopened due to coyotte508's comment, and due to the fact that the accepted answer on the duplicate is incorrect (returns real numbers instead of integers).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With c++11, using the standard [random library of c++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
  /* Seed */
  std::random_device rd;

  /* Random number generator */
  std::default_random_engine generator(rd());

  /* Distribution on which to apply the generator */
  std::uniform_int_distribution<long long unsigned> distribution(0,0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF);

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      std::cout << distribution(generator) << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](https://ideone.com/O0BtPY)

Comment: Have never seen the word `API` being used for this.

Comment: This solution is only generating large numbers . What if I want to generate the numbers in range of 0 - 2^64 ?

Comment: @Nabeel_Afzal this solution does generate numbers in the range [0, 2^64-1]. But since the numbers are purely random and chosen uniformly in this interval, 99% of the numbers generated will be over 2^56 as [2^56, 2^64] is over 100 times bigger than [0, 2^56].

Comment: You can mod the number to be smaller, like `myrnd %= 10000000000LL;`

Comment: @Déjàvu it would be preferable to change the distribution parameters than to MOD the generated numbers after the fact.

Answer (score 6):

As a uniformly random number in the range `[0, 2^64)` is just 64 random bits, you can just use the return values of `std::mt19937_64` directly:

```
#include <random>

int main () {
    std::mt19937_64 gen (std::random_device{}());

    std::uint64_t randomNumber = gen();
}
```

Note that seeding a Mersenne Twister engine with a single 32 bit seed is not optimal, for a better way, have a look at [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/109260/seed-stdmt19937-from-stdrandom-device).

Also note that the use of `rand` is generally discouraged these days. [Here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) is a talk by Stephan T. Lavavej on that topic.

Answer (score 2):

I would also consider using the OS facilities instead. All modern systems have cryptographic modules capable of generating very good random byte arrays of arbitrary length. Linux has [`getrandom()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html). Windows has [`CryptGenRandom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379942(v=vs.85).aspx). OpenBSD has [`arc4random`](http://man.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man3/arc4random.3?query=arc4random%26sec=3). iOS has [`SecRandomCopyBytes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/RandomizationReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecRandomCopyBytes). etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'wrote function that generates random 19 digit number It warks exactly like standard rand() function. It draws every digit from 19 digit number and stores them in an array, then it puts them together to make very big large random number.

```
unsigned long long Randomize()
{
    unsigned long long randnumber = 0;
    int digits[20];

    for (int i = 19; i >= 1; i--)
    {
      digits[i]=rand()%10:
    }
    for(int i=19; i>=1; i--)
    {
       unsigned long long power = pow(10, i-1);

        if (power%2 != 0 && power != 1)     //eliminates "bug" (which comes from long long power is not a float))
            power++;

        randnumber += power * digits[i];
    }
return randnumber;
}
```

To use this function you need to implement few libraries

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
```

example:

```
srand(time(NULL));
randomnumber = Randomize()%10000000+10000000;
```

in this case random number is a number from 10000000 to 20000000.

Answer (score 0):

*Late to answer the thread, but here is a simple approach*


We know that rand() in c++ can generate a random number nearly up to 32767 (source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rand-and-srand-in-ccpp/)
But if we do something like this:

```
long long random_num = (rand() * rand()) % 1000000000
```

Then it is guaranteed to generate a much larger random number than 32767. The modulus will determine the number of digits in the random number.

Comment: Multiplying two numbers is expensive so I don't think it would be optimal.

Answer (score -2):

If your `rand()` function only gives numbers in the range `[0, 2^15)`, then you can concatenate 5 numbers returned by `rand()` to get a number in the range `[0, 2^64)`.

Of course, there are other possible solutions (which may be even better). The `rand()` function in C++ library is usually a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). You may simply implement your own generator, using the same mathematical principles.

For example, the following code generates 64 bit random numbers:

```
unsigned long long rand64()
{
    static unsigned long long seed;
    seed = seed * 6364136223846793005 + 1442695040888963407;
    return seed;
}
```

The parameters `6364136223846793005` and `1442695040888963407` are those used by Donald Knuth.

The advantages and disadvantages of this method is discussed in the above wiki page. If high quality randomness is not needed, it could be a good choice.

Comment: Why the XOR actually? And why sections of 20 bits? Would you elaborate on these magical numbers please?

Comment: Could you please explain the logic behind the return statement?

Comment: 32768 is only 2^15, so doing these shifts by 20 won't fill all the bits.

Comment: Don't use `rand()` it generates *very* poor random numbers. Use the facilities in `<random>` instead. And for very large numbers (larger than 2^64) maybe use the functions in the GMP library.

Comment: So many casts (C style ones even). Pointless XOR operations (at least I don't see the point). Eeek.

Comment: @JesperJuhl The casts and XORs are both necessary. But the amount of shifts is incorrect, as is using a signed type.

Comment: @interjay my point is simply that this is really ugly and one should just use the stuff from `<random>` instead and the code will be clearer and the number quality better. This answer as written just makes me go 'eeew' - that looks like bad C.