# C++ random number for arbitrary integer (of fundamental type)

Tags: c++, random, typedef

I have a typedef for some arbitrary integer type, e.g.

```
typedef unsigned long long myint;
```

in other words, I don't know how it's actually defined, but I can guarantee that it's a [fundamental type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types).

I also have a variable instance of this type

```
myint n;
```

How do I assign `n` a random value that could be any value supported by `myint`?

---

Simply scaling the result of `rand()` to cover the range of `myint` would not be suitable since `myint` will likely be larger than the `int` type and therefore there will be inaccessible numbers.

Something like the following *would* work but seems rather inelegant and inefficient: Find the number of bits in `myint` and in `int`, and then concatenate a bunch of `rand()` numbers until `myint` is filled.

Comment: +1 for "Find the number of bits in myint and in int, and then concatenate a bunch of rand() numbers until myint is filled."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [generate random 64 bit integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120062/generate-random-64-bit-integer)

Comment: See [C++11 Random](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21096340/1621391)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the C++11 `<random>` library, `uniform_int_distribution` can give you any integer type:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<myint> dis(
    std::numeric_limits<myint>::min(), 
    std::numeric_limits<myint>::max());

myint num = dis(gen);
```

With unsigned types you can use the default constructor for `uniform_int_distribution`, which gives the range `0` to `numeric_limits<T>::max()`.

Comment: Huh, TIL that the 2nd parameter for the constructor is defaulted to the right thing already. (Just an observation, not critique. I think it's better to make it explicit.)

Answer (score 2):

**Use the [`#include <random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) library functions!**

---

As a bonus, those functions guarantee that the integers will be uniformly distributed across the given range.

```
//Initialize random engine
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 mt{ rd() };
std::uniform_int_distribution<myint> uid; //Default constructor - Range is 0 to myint-max

//'num' is random!
myint num = uid(mt);
```

Comment: 'num' will be the same value until you initialize `random_engine` with any changing with time value.